# Regex to match specific words the characters of which are delimited by special characters or space

Tags: regex

Can someone help me please?

I'm looking for a regex that does the following:
if i have this

> R.e.d

or

> R,e,d

or

> R e d

or

> R.e d

I want it to detect the word "Red" alone. I hope you get the idea, I just want a code that detects a certain word no matter how many / what type of delimiters are used between its characters. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm I found a way out.

For those who want the solution:

```
t(\s|[^A-Za-z]{0,2})+e(\s|[^A-Za-z]{0,2})+x(\s|[^A-Za-z]{0,2})+t(\s|[^A-Za-z]{0,2})+
```

not perfect but served me what i need

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

(R\D*e\D*d)